# Chat Transcript claims I pinned a message I cannot have pinned when I star it

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-transcript, chat-pins

Whenever I star a message in chat via the transcript, the chat transcript gets very confused. These are snippets of the Transcript and Live Feed for the same message:

> [image: Chat Transcript]

***Transcript***

> [image: Live Feed]

***Live Feed***

Note that I'm not a moderator/owner in the room in question, so there's no way I could have pinned it in the first place. It happens even when the message was never pinned in the past.

Comment: [I've reproduced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5g6ef.png) (just starred that message), not an owner of the tavern and it wasn't me who pinned it.

Comment: The whole transcript-pin-star mechanism need lots of love, many bugs with this combo, especially for room owners. Nice find though! :)